# Lastpass is filling hidden fields

Tags: javascript, html

This is already solved, so I'll be answering it myself. I wanted to share it here so that hopefully I can help someone else.

I ran into a problem while writing my application where LastPass prefills my TOTP token field on my login page. Not necessarily the end of the world, BUT, the TOTP field is hidden by default, and is displayed if the user's account has two-factor authentication enabled. This keeps it cleaner and less confusing for those that don't have it. It looks like this:

[image: My fancy two fac login page]

Anyways, when LastPass fills in that hidden field, it causes an invalid two-factor token to be submitted and thus throws an error. After a bunch of searching, I tried things like `data-lpignore`, `role=note` and others to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what worked for me, it's so simple it's annoying.

Basically, I added the following to the `$(document).ready` section of my login page's javascript:

```js
setTimeout(function () {
            if($("#tokenField").val()) {
                $("#tokenField").val('');
                $("#twoFactorSection").transition('slide down');
                two_fac_slid_down = true;
            }
        }, 500);
```

It basically waits for half a second, which has been enough time for LastPass to do it's thing on my test machines and checks if the TOTP field has anything in it. If it does, it clears it out and displays the field so the user can enter the **correct** token.

I hope this helps someone bypass a little frustration.

Comment: I'm not downvoting this but it's not a good idea.  At the very least you should use an event.  You never know how long something that is databound is going to take to load.